# Accessing protected members in a different assembly

Tags: c#, .net, protected, access-modifiers

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using Assembly2;

// DLL 1
namespace Assembly1
{
   class class1 : class2
   {
      static void Main()
      {
         Console.WriteLine(new class2().sample); //Cannot access. Protected means --> accessible to the derived classes right ? (But, note that this is a different assembly. Does not work because of that ?)
      }
   }
}

// DLL 2
namespace Assembly2
{
    public class class2
    {
      protected string sample = "Test";
    }
}
```

In the above simple code,

I cannot access the string `sample` in assembly 2 though I am deriving from `class2`

> ```
> From MSDN: 
>
> The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.
> ```

Does this definition stand only for the same assembly or can the protected members be accessed across assemblies ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the protected member from a different assembly, but only within a subclass (as normal for protected access):

```
// In DLL 1
public class Class3 : class2
{
    public void ShowSample()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sample);
    }
}
```

Note that your current code would fail even if the classes were in the same assembly.

Comment: It was a `treat` when my question gets answer from Jon Skeet. Thanks Jon. Silly of me though. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: One more question though. As for my understanding, if the `protected members can itself be accessible across assemblies`, then why is the need for `protected internal` ?

Comment: I tried making the member `sample` as `protected internal` and the behaviour is still the same ? I dont understand the signifance :(

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: No, a `protected internal` member can be accessed from *any* type within the same assembly.

Answer (score 1):

A protected member of a base class is accessible in a derived class **only if the access occurs through the derived class type**.

```
class class1:class2    
{    
      static void Main()
      {
         Console.WriteLine(new class1().sample);
      }
 }
```

now above code will run.